# "Variable might not have been initialized" in an implementation which will be execute after initialize

Tags: java

I have this peace of code:

```
private final static Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
private final static ScheduledFuture<?> consumeSchedule;

static{

    Runnable consumeMessages = () -> {

        //...Some code...

        //stop the printSchedule
        if(!mainThread.isAlive()){
            consumeSchedule.cancel(false); //Variable might not have been initialized
        }

    };

    //this will execute until the main thread will stop.
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    consumeSchedule = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(consumeMessages, 0, printRateMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
```

How I can avoid that error "Variable might not have been initialized", since it's obviously that the `cancel` will be called after the `printSchedule` will be initialized.

Or how to stop the consumeSchedule when the main thread has terminated?

Comment: Your IDE cannot guarantee that `consumeSchedule` is not `null` and warns you. Are you sure that's not the case? Ignore the warning... Not sure? Check for `null` before using `consumeSchedule`.

Comment: @QuinncyJones I am totally sure. I can't ignored it. Because it's an error from compiler. He doesn't know that the consumeMessages is executed only after initialize. If I check for null is the same error "...not have been init..."

Comment: “Not initialised” error is not the same as warning about possibly being `null`.   Checking for null is still “reading” that value (disallowed if not initialised).   For stopping the schedule, instead of calling `cancel`, can you throw an Exception?   Since `scheduleAtFixedRate` javadoc says “If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed.” https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it may seem a weird, but the error disappears if you convert the lambda expression to an anonymous class:

```java
Runnable consumeMessages = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Some code...
        if (!mainThread.isAlive()) {
            consumeSchedule.cancel(false);
        }
    }
};
```

This is because of the way lambda expressions work.

I think the below excerpt from the [Java Language Specification § 15.27.2. Lambda Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27) is applicable here:

> Unlike code appearing in anonymous class declarations, the meaning of names and the `this` and `super` keywords appearing in a lambda body, along with **the accessibility of referenced declarations**, are the same as in the surrounding context (except that lambda parameters introduce new names).

<sup>(Emphasis mine.)</sup>

So the accessibility of referenced declarations is effectively the same as if you had written:

```java
static {
    // Some code...
    if (!mainThread.isAlive()) {
        consumeSchedule.cancel(false);
    }

    // This will execute until the main thread will stop.
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    consumeSchedule = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(consumeMessages, 0, printRateMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

And now the reason why the compiler is complaining becomes more apparent: you have used `consumeSchedule` before you have assigned it. This follows from [Java Language Specification § 16. Definite Assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-16.html):

> Every local variable declared by a statement (§14.4.2, §14.14.1, §14.14.2, §14.20.3) and every blank `final` field (§4.12.4, §8.3.1.2) must have a *definitely assigned* value when any access of its value occurs.
>
> (...)
>
> For every access of a local variable or blank `final` field `x`, `x` must be definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.